# Finish button when trying to import not responding

Tags: android, eclipse

http://imgur.com/ZSzfMCX

In that picture, the finish button can be pressed and seems able to, but when I click it, its like nothing has happened. The button does highlight and dehighlight, but the window doesn't close and no action occurs. I've looked up solutions on this, but none of them work. I check for updates, and none were found. I've tried to "installing new software", but it says it has conflicting dependencies. So this is somewhat of a few problems combined together.

Extra info: Dependacies https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUwwy.jpg
Using eclipse adt

Answer (score 0):

You can not install DDMS, Development Tool etc.all at a time. Since they are interdependent so need to install one by one. **Firstly install DDMS only**